# python does not find pip-installed libraries when nodejs spawns a child process

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu-18.04

I am running a python script through python-shell in node.js.
When I install the python packages through apt-get, no problem. But when I do through pip, the spawned process does not find them even though running the exact same script in the terminal works perfectly.

What am I missing ?

Comment: `What am I missing ?` Probably the path to the correct python.

Comment: no checked that already.